# three miles down in a valley

Tags: articles

In my book there is the text:

> He made his way back to where Dad and Kate were half-dozing in the heat. "I have to rest, Dad," he said. He flopped to the ground in a dirty, broken heap.
> "I know," Dad said, "but first let Kate give you her ideas about the radio."
> "The radio isn't working," Chad said. "It doesn't even switch on."
> Kate roused. "The battery cables probably came loose in the crash. If the battery wasn't smashed, it should still work."
> "But how do you know it isn't ruined?"
> "We won't know until we can get some juice to it," she said.
> "Anyway," Chad said, "we're almost three miles down **in a valley**. The antenna wire is stuck up in the trees."
> "Really?" Kate said. "You saw it?"
> He nodded.

Why is the author of this text using the article "a" before valley? This valley is where they had crashed and both the author and the reader know that; so, it should be "in the valley" with article "the" (as for the crash - "The battery cables probably became loose **in the crash**" see text above).

Please help explain this to me.

Answer (score 2):

"The" would make it sound like the valley was their destination, or that it is a special valley, bit it is just some valley where they crashed. From an outside perspective you would also say: "They crashed in **a** valley", not "they crashed in **the** valley", unless it is a special valley.
Also, they could be down any valley for the radio not to work, it doesn't have to be a specific valley, that's why it's just **a** valley.

So, "a/an" to mean "in general", "one of many"

"The" if its specific

Answer (score 1):

Because it makes more sense to use the indefinite article **a** in this case. Not that **the** is incorrect, though.

The logic is that the character is bemoaning the grim situation he and his fellow adventurers are in. *a valley* is a general reference in this case as the character is deliberately unspecific about the particular valley they're in: it symbolizes desolation, wilderness, and the like.